# Java GUI: Instantiating a complex pop-up window's components each time it's opened vs storing them

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jdialog

I have a fairly complex JDialog window that can be opened with a button and which forces the user to close it before moving on. It is a sequence creator for a simulation, so it shouldn't be opened too frequently. (The JDialog window itself contains about 15 labels, 10 buttons, 10 checkboxes, few text fields, a list and a table. 800x400)

Which is the better practice, to have the main panel and its components ready in the background, or instantiate it and through the constructors build up the panel that is going to be destroyed when the window is closed?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a very resource heavy dialog to either create or keep in memory.  If you'd have mentioned several *thousand* components, maybe..  My first approach with these types of dialogs is to 1) create them dynamically, only when needed, then.. 2) keep a reference to them until such times as I see `OutOfMemoryError` (and even then, I'd look to other parts of the app. first)

Comment: "which is the better practice" is not a well fitting question for stackoverflow since it is primarily opinion-based. My opinion: Go for instantiating and see whether you're "happy" with it. If it takes "too long" to open, start wrack your brain about optimization - not before that.

Comment: Making it in the "non-static" style is quite a bigger struggle, therefore I would do it only if saved a reasonable amount of resources. It's not an opinion-based question.. It is totally technical.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Java have it's own internal caching for various things, (also applies to the spawn of new components). Take a look at this:

```
    public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        long l11 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new JDialog();
        long l12 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long l21 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new JDialog();
        long l22 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("dialog 1: " + (l12 - l11) + " ms");
        System.out.println("dialog 2: " + (l22 - l21) + " ms");
      }
    }
```

Output:

```
    dialog 1: 54 ms
    dialog 2: 1 ms
```

You can replace `new JDialog();` with any other swing component (or many), even custom components created by you and you will have similar results.

Take in account that you will have to also reset that your panel/components so is better to start with a fresh (new) one. This will also eliminate all the possible errors/bugs while maintaining that panel.

Comment: What are the results if the dialogs are created **on the EDT?**  I bet it would be significantly different.

Comment: Then you will lose the bet. :) Too bad we can't add code in the comments, but you can make the test by executing that code on the EDT (i suppose you already know how to do'it, but i write this for others: using javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater method).

Comment: You can edit your answer to show revised code. Your example may be measuring [JVM performance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html). You'll also want to look at memory consumption.